Why was there only one favorable blessing in Genesis 27 but many in Genesis 49?
In Genesis 27, Isaac has only one favorable blessing which was given to Jacob. But there is no blessing left for Esau. In the terms of an actual  favorable blessing: a “prayer calling for divine care, protection, or favor.”
“A small gift from the heavens”
Instead Esau said to his father, “Have you but one blessing, my father? Bless me, even me also, O my father.” And Esau lifted up his voice and wept.
But fast forward a little to Genesis 49-Jacob blesses his 12 sons. Well some receive actual  favorable blessings while others not so much. But nonetheless he blessed quite a few. I didn’t add the entire text but here’s the ones who got favorable blessings:
Judah, your brothers will praise you.
Your hand will be on the neck of your enemies…
Zebulun will live by the coast.  He will have ships by the coast.  His border will go as far as Sidon.
Issachar is a strong donkey,  lying down between the saddlebags.
When he sees that his resting place is good…
Dan will hand down decisions [a] for his people
as one of the tribes of Israel…
Dan will be a snake on a road,
a viper on a path…
Asher’s food will be rich.  He will provide delicacies fit for a king.
Naphtali is a doe set free  that has beautiful fawns.
Joseph is a fruitful tree,  a fruitful tree by a spring,  with branches climbing over a wall…
Benjamin is a ravenous wolf.  In the morning he devours his prey.  In the evening he divides the plunder.
Another follow up question is that if you take your time to read the blessings given in Genesis 49, many of them seem to fortell what will happen. Such as “will be attacked by a band of raiders” or a different one that says “Archers provoked him, shot at him” there’s more…but, how does Jacob  know these things will happen? or is he merely speaking figuratively??
—I don’t know whether I can ask about comparisons between stories. If not, please remove the question.

It's a fair question. The post could be improved if the passages in question were quoted with references.

You mean quote the entire text in Genesis? Should I? I thought it was too long

This is more involved that it appears:
The formal blessing of the birthright (usually the oldest son) had several functions:

The birthright blessing came with a double portion of inherited land (Gen 48:22, Deut 21:17)
The birthright also came with the acknowledgement that this (usually eldest) son would become the priest of the family
The birthright also came with the acknowledgement that this son would be the leader of the family
For some, this leader responsibility also came with the promise that he would be one of the progenitors of the promised Messiah.

Now, in the list of Jacob's prophecies in Gen 49, not all are blessings.  Significantly, Reuben the firstborn was cursed:

Gen 49:4 - Uncontrolled as the waters, you will no longer excel,
because you went up to your father’s bed, onto my couch, and defiled
it.

Thus, Reuben did not receive the blessing of the birthright; the blessings and privileges of the birthright were split a divided among the other sons, specifically:

Judah became the leader of the family and also the progenitor of Messiah, Gen 49:9-12
Joseph received a double portion of land in Manasseh and Ephraim, Gen 49:22-26
Levi received the priesthood (Gen 49:7)

Some of the pronouncements/prophecies are curses such as Benjamin's (Gen 49:27), and Reuben's (Gen 49:3, 4), and Issachar appears to become enslaved (Gen 49:14), etc. The prophecy to "scatter Levi in Jacob and disperse you in Israel" (Gen 49:7) became the blessing of the priesthood.
Thus, Jacob's pronouncements in Gen 49 should simply be seen as prophecies about the tribes that would come from the 12 brothers.

Your right! I re-read them and Ishacar does seem to become enslaved. Are the prophesies of these things actually happening similar to some sort of vision Jacob had or just a prophesy that may or may not have come to pass?

@Lyd - that is the subject of another question - too big to answer in comments.

No problem. I’ll ask a separate question.


Why was there only one favorable blessing in Genesis 27 but many in Genesis 49?

Thank you for asking this question. Researching it has caused me to learn more about the complexity of blessings.

There were two positive blessings given by Isaac in Genesis 27.
There is a positive blessing given by Jacob/Israel in Genesis 48:14-16.
In Genesis 49 Jacob blessed each of his sons with a blessing that was appropriate for each son.



The blessings given by Isaac.

A blessing is the bestowing of privilege, right, responsibility, or favor. A blessing may also contain statements that relate to the character of the receiver.
Isaac's blessing on Jacob
Genesis 27

28 May God give you of the dew of heaven
and of the fatness of the earth
and plenty of grain and wine.
29 Let peoples serve you,
and nations bow down to you.
Be lord over your brothers,
and may your mother's sons bow down to you.
Cursed be everyone who curses you,
and blessed be everyone who blesses you!

Isaac's blessing on Esau
Genesis 27

38 Esau said to his father, “Have you but one blessing, my father? Bless me, even me also, O my father.” And Esau lifted up his voice and wept.
39 Then Isaac his father answered and said to him:
“Behold, away from the fatness of the earth shall your dwelling be,
and away from the dew of heaven on high.
40 By your sword you shall live,
and you shall serve your brother;
but when you grow restless
you shall break his yoke from your neck.”

Esau does receive a blessing. Isaac acknowledges that his life would be hard and there will be service to Jacob - but not forever. Isaac's blessing is that Esau will eventually be free. After giving everything to Jacob the best blessing Isaac could offer was freedom.
Esau's blessing is appropriate to who he was, to his character, a nomadic hunter and to his character, someone who valued materially meeting his immediate physical needs (selling his birthright for food because he was hungry).
There are two blessings. One blessing focuses on God's protection and enrichment of Jacob and the other is a statement of Esau's character and eventual freedom.
A blessing in the Old Testament may include statements of privilege, right, responsibility, or favor along with statements related to the character of the receiver.

Jacob's blessing of Ephraim.
Genesis 48


14 And Israel stretched out his right hand and laid it on the head of Ephraim, who was the younger, and his left hand on the head of Manasseh, crossing his hands (for Manasseh was the firstborn).  15 And he blessed Joseph and said,
“The God before whom my fathers Abraham and Isaac walked,
the God who has been my shepherd all my life long to this day,
16 the angel who has redeemed me from all evil, bless the boys;
and in them let my name be carried on, and the name of my fathers Abraham and Isaac;
and let them grow into a multitude in the midst of the earth.”


In Genesis 49 Jacob tells of future events.

Genesis 49

Then Jacob called his sons and said, “Gather yourselves together, that I may tell you what shall happen to you in days to come.
2 “Assemble and listen, O sons of Jacob,
listen to Israel your father.

What follows is a series of judgements based on the actions driven by the character of the individual. For those sons who had demonstrated poor character the judgements were negative. For those sons who had demonstrated good character the judgements were positive. The words "bless" and "blessing" don't appear until Joseph is brought up in verses 25 and 26.
Genesis 49

28 All these are the twelve tribes of Israel. This is what their father said to them as he blessed them, blessing each with the blessing suitable to him.

Scripture tells us that Jacob/Israel blessed each son with the blessing that was suitable to him.
Therefore, blessings can be both positive and negative.
Blessings are not always about getting something the receiver (or the reader) identifies as "good". In this case some of the blessings may appear mixed but each of them is told that they would survive and grow into significant tribes. None of them were extinguished during the centuries spent in Egypt.

Thank you! Yes, it does seem like in the past few decades the word “ blessing” would be identified as receiving something “good”. I didn’t view Esau’s blessing as eventually being good by leading up to freedom. Thank you for explaining it.
